# Unable to call kotlin fragment from java class

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have created new dialog fragment in kotlin but my project was in java. I have tried display dialog from another java fragment.

I called from java like below

```
   new AlertFragment().show(getChildFragmentManager(),"AlertFragment");
```

It's shows build error with message

> error: cannot find symbol class AlertFragment

what's would be issue and how do I resolve it?

Thanks in advance

**Code of AlertFragment**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil

class AlertFragment : BaseDialogFragment() {
private var binding: FragmentAlertBinding? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_alert, container, false)
    return binding?.root
}
}
```

**BaseDialogFagment** is java class

```
 class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
```

**Note :** I'm using Androidx lib for support.

Comment: Can u paste the code for alert fragment? And the full stacktrace plz

Comment: If dialog fragment is in kotlin . Then you are only missing an import for `AlertFragment`.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari added fragment code

Comment: @ADM I have imported alert fragment already

Comment: What is the version of Kotlin you are using? Did you use the ```getInstance``` pattern?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari 1.3.31

Comment: What does `BaseDialogFragment` extend? What version of fragment library do you use? (full fragment package name). Also, can you reference any Kotlin code from Java code? (for example create empty kotlin class, then empty java class and try to instantiate that kotlin class in java class method). If you use IDE, is Kotlin's `AlertDialog` import highlighted as red? We need more information, because as it is now it builds perfectly for me in given configuration.

Comment: @xinaiz i'm using `androidx`, BaseDialogFragment extends `DialogFragment` and I did not get any import issue.